# Service that returns an object with IDisposable?

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, idisposable

OK, so... I have this project that I'm working on that is trying to implement a WCF (.SVC) service to return an object with IDisposible. We use it something like this:

```
FactoryService client = new FactoryService();

LibraryFactory factory = client.CreateLibraryFactory("Hello Library");

using (IErrorWatcher watcher = client.CreateErrorWatcher(factory, "This is a test, this is only a test...")) 
{
    try 
    {
        int a = 0; int b = 1;
        int c = b / a; //Force errror
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        watcher.SetError(ex);
    }
}
```

We're doing this so that the Dispose method can be used to trigger logging. Problem is, we're getting this error: ErrorWatcher: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

It IS implementing IDisposible, so I assume this is a problem with the service. Are there any Ts we need to dot or I's we need to cross, or is this even doable?
`
FactoryService code looks like this:
    using Cloud.Library;

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface FactoryService {
    [OperationContract]
    LibraryFactory CreateLibraryFactory(string applicationId);

    [OperationContract]
    ErrorWatcher CreateErrorWatcher(LibraryFactory factory, string eventURI);
}
```

`

Any and all clues appreciated.

Comment: Post your factoryservice code.

Comment: Please post the signature of `IErrorWatcher`, is it `interface IErrorWatcher : IDisposeable { ...`?

Answer (score 1):

I bet your class implements `IDisposable` **at the server**. When you create a proxy of it to use the proxy at the client side, the proxy will reflect all the methods but **no interfaces**. Technically it means that despite your class being disposable on the server, the proxy at the client side doesn't implement this interface by default. You could add the interface to the proxy manually for the client side.

What could be important however, is that in case of disposable objects, calling `Dispose` on the client to make it call `Dispose` on the server counterpart often doesn't make much sense as the lifetime of the server side object is restricted to a single method call anyway.

This means that when you call `Dispose` at the client side, the server creates **a new** instance of the server side object for the lifetime of the new call and calls `Dispose` on it.

Comment: Exactly. The service has to expose itself in such a way that it can be recreated on the other side (whether that's by a .NET consumer, or from any other framework etc.). Having every single interface and/or base class contained within the reference for everything exposed by the service would be a) extremely bloated and unwieldy and b) useless to non-.NET consumers.

Comment: Confering with our architect, that does seem to be the problem. He's ready to scrap this as a solution. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make it work? Including for non.NET consumers? Open to any and all ideas.

Comment: If the goal is to have a disposable object at the client, you just add the interface but it doesn't make much sense, there is nothing to dispose about the proxy. If you want to dispose at the server but you want to control it from the client, you have a bad time as this sounds tricky if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Soap service client inherits from System.ServiceModel.ClientBase:

```
public partial class MySoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MySoap>, MySoap {..}
```

ClientBase has implemented IDisposable interface:

```
public abstract class ClientBase<TChannel> : ICommunicationObject, IDisposable where TChannel : class
```

So it looks it should be disposed by a programmer. Is it really needed? I dont know.
I just did:

```
MySoap my_soap = new MySoapClient(binding, endpoint);
using (my_soap as IDisposable)
{
...
}
```